# Как адаптировать maphilight под свой сайт?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как адаптировать плагин ***[maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/#maphilight)*** под свои нужды. Выдернул весь код вот из этого [примера](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html), подцепил свою картинку вместо карты США, нарисовал новые <AREA> для своей картинки, начинаю проверять на своей локальной машине, а мне FireBug пишет:

```
$(".map").maphilight is not a function
[Прерывать на этой ошибке]

$('.map').maphilight();
```

Ничего не работает, никакой подсветки.
Может у кого-нить есть опыт при работе с данным плагином. Поделитесь пожалуйста своим богатейшим опытом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Необходимо было подключить корректный файл [jquery.maphilight.js](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight/blob/master/jquery.maphilight.js).